# Freeze time during test, Mock singleton objects

Tags: scala, playframework, mockito, specs2

I'm trying to freeze the clock during specs execution. Something like [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop) but for Scala/Play 2.4

It's also related to mocking singleton objects since I would like to be able to specify return value for `ZonedDateTime.now()`.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to test. It may be you just need a different approach on how your write or test the class.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to always inject an interface providing a `now` method to any method needing to know the current time. Then you can use Mockito and `specs2-mock` to return exactly the time you want

```
import org.specs2._, mock._

class TimeSpec extends Specification with Mockito { def is = s2"""

    test with event creation some specific time $time1

  """

  def time1 = {
    val time = mock[DateTime]
    val timestamp = new DateTime("2016-01-30 12:00:00")  
    time.now returns timestamp

    val event = Event.create(time)
    event.dt === timestamp
  }
}

trait Time {
  def now: DateTime
}

case class Event(dt: DateTime)

object Event {
  def create(time: DateTime): Event = 
    Event(time.now)
}
```